# Adding variables to a function's scope during a call

Tags: javascript

I want to allow a `locals` object to have all its variables be within the scope when a function is called. For example:

```
function test() {
  console.log(string)
}

var locals = {
  string: 'test'
}

function callTest(fn, locals) {
  // INSERT MAGIC
  fn()
}

callTest(test, locals) // -> should log 'test' without any errors
```

What I'm trying to avoid:

```
function(locals) {
  with (locals) {
    console.log(string)
  }
}
```

Use case: I want to create a templating system with a callback.
The locals should really be locals, not a "locals" object.

```
module.exports = function(callback) {
  callback(null, string)
}
```

Yes, I can do the following, but it's ugly. For now, this is how I'm doing it:

```
module.exports = function(locals, callback) {
  callback(null, locals.string)
}
```

Is this possible at all, or even in any programming language?

Comment: That's what function arguments are for.

Comment: it doesn't matter. my question isn't how to fix a my use-case scenario, but to solve this particular problem.

Comment: True. However, particular problems shouldn't be an excuse to a bad programming practice.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand exactly, but how about this: (does log 'test')

```
function test( locals ) {
    console.log( locals.string );
}

var locals = {
    string: 'test';
}

function callTest(fn, locals) {
    // INSERT MAGIC
  fn( locals );
}

callTest(test, locals); // -> should log 'test' without any errors
```

Comment: OK, so what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 0):

I know you aren't looking for alternatives (in terms of solving your issue). I won't argue with that. The only thing I can think of, *without* using global variables or function arguments (which would be the *normal* way to do it):

```
function test() {
    console.log( this.string );
}

function callTest(fn, locals) {
    // INSERT MAGIC
    fn.call(locals);
}

var locals = {
    string: 'test';
}

callTest(test, locals);
```

The only discrepancy with your requirements is that `locals` becomes `this`.

Comment: yeah, thought about it. but then things get annoying when you have callbacks, so i would rather just use `locals`.

Answer (score 0):

Either use context properties (`this.property`) or read the linked article and use the `Function` constructor which can absolutely get you what you want.

> [Templating without the with Statement](http://blog.jankuca.com/post/10848341942/templating-with-statement)

Comment: looked into it and it worked, but the problem now is that I don't know how to keep the scope within `test` since I basically have to rewrite the function. ex.: `var txt = 'asdf'; function test() {console.log(string + txt)};`

Comment: The `Function` constructor creates a function that can only access the global scope + the arguments and context you provide. What do you need the closure for in a templating system? If you have helper functions, pass them as arguments along with the locals.